# Create facebook App with old facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have some problem with the Facebook API 2.4. 
By default FB creates new app with the 2.4 version.
Is there a way to create an app using the API 2.3?

I just need a time to fix my sw for new version.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a new App will only be able to use the latest/current API version, you can´t switch to an older one. If you really need to use something that is deprecated, you will have to use an App created before v2.4 was introduced.

Comment: Why didn't I create an app before :(

Comment: you should not build something on a deprecated api anyway ;)

Comment: Facebook removed access to user groups after v2.3. Now it only allows access to user-managed groups. I, however, need to access all user groups for my app to work. Do you know of any way around this and why Facebook would remove that? I can still generate an access token for v2.3, but it only lasts a few minutes and it needs to be associated with an app for it to be extended.