# Is it still possible to make a new Facebook App with older API versions (ex v2.3)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

Because of a context I need to use the older versions of the Facebook API and use the v2.3. When i make a new facebook AppId the version is read only to v2.6 and i get to see this hint [image]

I really hope i can still make apps with older versions, but not sure how yet. Does anyone had this situation before and can lead me to something that helps? Thank you.

Comment: I found this thread from last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322141/create-facebook-app-with-old-facebook-api  wonder if this is still the case?

Comment: Why? v2.3 stops working for everyone a year from now anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new App, you can only use the current API version. There is no way to downgrade below that version.

It would be pointless anyway, don´t build something new on an API that is deprecated, because it would stop working sooner or later.

Edit: Well, that answer in the other thread is from me. Of course it´s still valid, and it will always be ;)